# Python setuptools in WinXP bails out of install with uninformative error

Tags: python, python-2.7

Followed the instructions on the official page for this py package which is here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows-7-or-graphical-install

'For Windows 7 and earlier, download ez_setup.py using your favorite web browser or other technique and "run" that file.'

When I try to run, it quits out not long into the process with the following most informative (AHEM !) error:

> Extracting in c:\docume~1\owl\locals~1\temp\tmpu31ctv   
>  
>   Now working in c:\docume~1\owl\locals~1\temp\tmpu31ctv\setuptools-5.4.2 
>  
>   Installing Setuptools 
>  
>   **Something went wrong during the installation.
>  
>   See the error message above.**

!?!?!
Any clues as to what might be wrong ?

Comment: Is it 32bit or 64bit Windows? Have you tried downloading the setuptools package manually, unpacking to a dir, then running cmd, navigating to the dir and run: python setup.py install? http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools

Comment: @tsaulic, it is 32bit Windows XP.  I did download the setuptools package manually and unpacked to a dir. From there I opened setup.py in IDLE and ran [F5] which gave me the results I reported above. Why should there be a difference doing it the way I did vs running from a cmd shell ?  Is there a more robust environment PATH in the cmd shell ?

Comment: there's a difference. When you run it via 'python setup.py install' you are telling the setup.py script which action you want to perform - install. There is also an option to build it and build/install with verbose option. Try: python setup.py -v install

Comment: @tsaulic, you provided the solution, but not in the way that you may have thought. I clicked on the link you provided above, namely:<br />   [link](lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools)<br /> and used the .exe version there for win32/python2.7  All is well. So now my question is, why the heck does the official python package site (link above in the original question) not provided *.exe's of these installers ??

Comment: glad it worked then. I just posted that as a last resort in case you don't want to try manual installation anymore. Sometimes it's good to learn how to deal with some issues like environment variables and best practices for installing some software. But it's also ok to just download and install the binaries via such a package :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

I've always ended up with headaches trying to manually install python libraries on windows. I recommend using the excellent installers on this site:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Here's setuptools:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools

Comment: Yup, that's how I resolved it, as @tsaulic mentioned the same site earlier. Thanks !

Comment: I didn't even notice the comments! Glad we're on the same page. I really don't even bother trying on windows anymore, just go straight to that site.

Comment: Also if you think my answer is the best solution please accept it, even though tsaulic technically beat me to it ;)

Comment: Anders is right :) +1 mate. Btw. Ditch windows for linux if youve got a chance :)

Comment: Windows is good at a lot of things, but unfortunately doesn't play very nice with python. Linux+python is a match made in heaven.

Comment: @tsaulic @anders; I've made steps in that direction; I very recently created a dual-boot system with WinXP & Ubuntu v14.

Answer (score 1):

After unpacking the setuptools to a directory, navigate to it via cmd line and execute:

```
python setup.py -v install
```

then paste if you've got any more errors. Alternatively, do what I've already mentioned in a comment to your question and what anders has posted as an answer.

Comment: Yup, that's what I did (the "Alternatively" part). I tried fixing my comment above but the StackOverflow's forum rules won't let me edit it after so many times, and, worse, I tried to give you an Up-Vote on this reply but StackOverflow won't let me because I don't have a high enough rep yet. That seems ridiculous; you deserve my praise in that way. I've also been locked out of other basic functionality on this forum for the same reason. Until I increase my rep score past 50, these forum rules are maddening ! (perhaps I should submit a complaint to the Meta Stack Exchange ?)........

Comment: ......oh, hell, it probably won't let me lodge a complaint until my rep score is higher! Aaaaarrrrggghhh !)

Comment: Thats ok, very soon youll get there. And the rules are strict only to prevent trolls and abusers to ruin the community.